# angular: how can we access the class name in the app-root from local component?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have three main pages and multiple child pages with each inherit its style from parent css.

**country.routes.ts**

```
 ...
 path: '',
 children: [
    { 
      path: '/country', 
      component: CountryComponent, 
      data: {
        cssClass: 'country',
      },
    },
    { 
      path: ':countryId/city', 
      component: CityComponent ,
      data: {
        cssClass: 'country-city',
      },
    },
    {
      path: ':countryId/fact', 
      component: FactComponent,
      data: {
        cssClass: 'country-fact',
      },
    },
...
```

CSS class is inserted to the a div just below the `app-root` like this

**index.html (just rough html representation)**

```
<app-root>
 <div clas="country/country-fact/country-city">
  <header></header>
  <div>
   <route-outlet>
    <main>
     <!-- content -->
    </main>
   </route-outlet>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
 </div>
</app-root>
```

**in the main.scss (global style)**

```
country {
  background-color:red;
}
country-city {
  background-color:blue;
}
.country-fact {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

Because this is angular, therefore I want to exploit the view encapsulation and declare the style in the component declarator

**country.component.ts**

@component({

```
 ...
 styles: ['
  :host-context(.country) main{
    background-color:red;
 ','
   :host-context(.country) header{
     display:none;
    }
 '],
```

**country-city.component.ts**

@component({

```
 ...
 styles: ['
  :host-context(.country-city) main{
    background-color:blue;
 '],
```

**country-fact.component.ts**

@component({

```
 ...
 styles: ['
  :host-context(.country) main{
    background-color:purple;
 '],
```

***From reading and tutorials:***

The [tutorial](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/) I read, so I change/edit parent's css by using the ':host' or ':host-context(.selector) .change-selector`, but it doesn't say I can use the`:host-context()` at the body or the app-root level.

I tried nested `:host` or `:host{ :host-context()}, both were failed.

In the https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/, it says that it is possible to select at the body level with the puseudo class but it does not work. I read some other article which I can't find the link, it says the `:host-context` is similar to `:host` with a selector, then I can only select my parent's class and not at the body level.

Comment: Where are your components located in the hierarchy? Under `<main>`?? Can you create a small example on stackblitz.com?

Comment: The components are defined under the <main>

Comment: Dis you see my answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `main` element is not part of the component you are applying the style to

From reading the official documentation for `host-context` (https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host-context), you can only apply CSS styles to the elements INSIDE the component, based on some conditions outside of the component

> The following example applies a background-color style to all  elements **inside** the component, only if some ancestor element has the CSS class theme-light.

```
:host-context(.theme-light) h2 {
  background-color: #eef;
}
```

So to achieve what you are trying to do, you need to set these styles inside the component that has the `main` tag, or have the `main` tag inside your country components, or change the rules to target an element inside the country components (not the `main` tag)

Comment: thanks, I see it now the `host-context` selects a theme class inside the parent component's class, not any classes on the dom. I am under a time constraint not sure if I can change, but I will keep in mind for the next time I work on this.

Comment: No it can select any class up the dom tree. But the rules that you specify will only apply to the component setting these rules only.